# How to remove constrains from UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, constraints

How to remove constrains from UIView?

[image: constrains on uiview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck 'Use Autolayout' checkbox, under the first tab of the Xcode Utility Area

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the constraint in the left view and press the delete button. This works for me.